# How to conditionally assign attribute value in angular 2?

Tags: angular, attributes, conditional-statements

I'm trying to learn the Angular 2. I have a simple material input tag and I wish to set it's value on a conditon.

```
<md-input value="dataSelected ? {{selectedDataName}} : ''"></md-input>
```

I tried to set [value] or dataSelected as {{dataSelected}} or (dataSelected) but it doesn't do the trick.
Can someone lead me into right direction?

Comment: are you getting any error when you set it ?

Comment: No errors. If i leave it as: value="dataSelected ? {{selectedDataName}} : '' "
The result in field is: dataSelected ? TestName1 : ''  - so it correctly converted only the selectedDataName.

What should be the correct syntax in your opinion? I'll test it out and show you the result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `value="dataSelected ? {{selectedDataName}} : ''"` you can set it `value` with below possibile ways :

```
<md-input [attr.value]="dataSelected ? selectedDataName : ''"></md-input>
```

or

```
<md-input [value]="dataSelected ? selectedDataName : ''"></md-input>
```

or

```
<md-input value="{{dataSelected ? selectedDataName : ''}}"></md-input>
```

Comment: It seems that <md-input [value]="dataSelected ? selectedDataName : ''"></md-input> had worked as expected. Thank you !

Comment: @Morgoth Not sure if it's for different browsers or if it's the tooth of time biting the suggesting but on my system, I get a title popup anyway. The resolution I had to use is binding to a backing field being set *condition?"title text":null*. So vasically the same junk as suggested but my unk has to be null (or undefined) not empty string.

Comment: @KonradViltersten [This short article](https://www.joshuacolvin.net/angular-conditional-attributes/) explains that `null` causes Angular to remove/completely omit the attribute itself, instead of adding an *empty* attribute. Small but important difference for your case (and mine).

Comment: @KonradViltersten just to add a **nasty caveat** to the previous comment: `[maxlength]="null"` omits the attribute, but `[maxLength]="null"` (notice the capital L) converts to `maxlength="0"` (!!!)